# Concurrency on sqlite database using python

Tags: python, database, sqlite, concurrency, locking

There is a list of data that I want to deal with. However I need to process the data with multiple instances to increase efficiency.

Each time each instance shall take out one item, delete it from the list and process it with some procedures.

First I tried to store the list in a sqlite database, but sqlite allows multiple read-locks which means multiple instances might get the same item from the database.

Is there any way that makes each instance will get an unique item to process?
I could use other data structure (other database or just file) if needed.

By the way, is there a way to check whether a DELETE operation is successful or not, after executing cursor.execute(delete_query)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about another field in db as a flag (e.g. PROCESSING, UNPROCESSED, PROCESSED)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you'll need to start up multiple instances of the python interpreter to get true concurrency with python (or at least multiple executing processes so you could:

- make 1 broker process that tells the others which record they're allowed to take (via something like [0mq](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3apython/) for instance), this could effectively make your broker a bottleneck though.
- section off parts of your database per process, if your data is easy divisible (ascending numbers for primary keys for example).

things like [greenlets](http://greenlet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) and [tasklets](http://www.stackless.com/wiki/Tasklets) are really executed one after the other, they switch really fast due to the fact that they don't have the true threading/process overhead but they're not executed truly concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to generate the items in a single process and pass them for processing to multiple worker processes e.g.:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def process(item):
    pass # executed in worker processes

def main():
    p = Pool() # use all available CPUs
    for result in p.imap_unordered(process, open('items.txt')):
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Can I use multiprocessing module if I need to run instances on different computers concurrently?

Comment: yes, use BaseManager to access a shared queue (.put/.get jobs). As an alternative you could try [`celery`](http://celeryproject.org/) (a higher level interface)

Answer (score 0):

Why not read in all the items from the database and put them in a queue? You can have a worker thread get at item, process it and move on to the next one.